# Perform action when opening app for the second time

Tags: ios, swift, events

When I open the app it fires the events `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` form my View Controller but when I close it and run it again it does not call any of them.

Any idea?

Comment: More info is needed.

Comment: You are not running the app again, you are simply returning to the already running app.

Comment: @rmaddy how can I fire an action when returning to the app?

Comment: Read the documentation for `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on application states. Here is a link I found online outlining the different states:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/understand-the-states-and-transitions-of-an-ios-app/

What you really want is to be notified when your app becomes active.

Probably the easiest way is to implement the function `applicationDidBecomeActive()` in your app delegate. That will be called when your app becomes active as the foreground app either on launch, or when it returns to the foreground as the active app.

Note that if you want that notification sent to some object other than the app delegate you can listen for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification.